# Passing results of "find" to zenity

Tags: bash, find

The result of the following script:

```
results=$(find -iname "*.mp4")
echo $results;
```

is something like:

```
file1 file2 file3
```

How do I pass the results of the find command to a variable, as it is shown when I run the following command in terminal:

```
find -iname "*.mp4"
```

which prints:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Comment: How do you want to use this result?

Comment: @Mat I want to pass the results to zenity --text-info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `echo $results` do `echo "$results"`.

**Update**:

The difference between the 2 is that in the 1st case `echo` receives many parameters and in the 2nd case it receives only one parameter.  This is because *variable substitution* occurs before *parameter parsing*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, an example on zenity lists, it read the result from `find`,
and generate an array, then pass on to zenity:

```
#!/bin/bash

List=()
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
    List=("${List[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find . -iname '*.mp4' -print0)

zenity --list --column "Item" "${List[@]}"
```